# AO Smith Electric Water Heater that keeps needing to be reset

Tags: water-heater

Recently replaced the thermostat but I keep needing to reset the water heater due to cold water and then it becomes scalding water for a short time before it goes cold again. It's an 80-gallon unit

Comment: Are you adjusting both thermostats?

Comment: I'm assuming this model has some electronic control board??  If so, is it displaying any status/error codes?

Comment: Is the power on 24 hr a day ? I had one with two thermostats. , one of them only had power at night.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will look for 2 thermostat and a control board